# Should we use “puzzle” as part as tag names?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently tags called [puzzle-creation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-creation), [logic-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-puzzle), [einsteins-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/einsteins-puzzle), [online-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-puzzle), [puzzle-hunts](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-hunts).

Should the word “puzzle” be part of the tag name? After all everything on this site is about puzzles.

(The answer may be different for different tags, e.g. I'm leaning towards [logic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic) but [einsteins](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/einsteins) wouldn't make much sense.)

Answer (score 4):

[einsteins-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/einsteins-puzzle) is an exception, as it a actually refers to something by the name of "Einstein's Puzzle", which is both a computer game and a well-known logic problem.

The other tags contain words people would intuitively search for. Maybe in the future it would be a good idea to synonymize [puzzle-creation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-creation) and [creation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creation), for instance - but people would still likely search using the word "puzzle" in these tags.

For this reason, I think they should be kept, even if only as synonyms.

Comment: Agreed, similarly, the tag "logic" doesn't really convey the same thing as "logic-puzzle".

Answer (score 0):

I think [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle), as well as the other tags that have `puzzle` in them, are quite redundant. Therefore, i think we should remove all the tags that contain `puzzle`, except those that wouldn't make sense without it, like [einsteins-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/einsteins-puzzle).

Comment: The problem with this is, that they will keep getting created. If you have commonly typed tags that are inappropriate just make them synonyms.